# What's the difference between GradientTape, implicit_gradients, gradients_function and implicit_value_and_gradients?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to switch to TensorFlow eager mode and I find the documentation of `GradientTape`, `implicit_gradients`, `gradients_function` and `implicit_value_and_gradients` confusing.

What's the difference between them? When should I use one over the other?

The [intro point in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager) does not mention implicit* functions at all, yet almost all of the examples in TensorFlow repository seems to use that method for computing gradients.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 4 ways to automatically compute gradients when eager execution is enabled (actually, they also work in graph mode):

- `tf.GradientTape` context records computations so that you can call `tfe.gradient()` to get the gradients of any tensor computed while recording with regards to any trainable variable.
- `tfe.gradients_function()` takes a function (say `f()`) and returns a gradient function (say `fg()`) that can compute the gradients of the outputs of `f()` with regards to the parameters of `f()` (or a subset of them).
- `tfe.implicit_gradients()` is very similar but `fg()` computes the gradients of the outputs of `f()` with regards to all trainable variables these outputs depend on.
- `tfe.implicit_value_and_gradients()` is almost identical but `fg()` also returns the output of the function `f()`.

Usually, in Machine Learning, you will want to compute the gradients of the loss with regards to the model parameters (ie. variables), and you will generally also be interested in the value of the loss itself. For this use case, the simplest and most efficient options are `tf.GradientTape` and `tfe.implicit_value_and_gradients()` (the other two options do not give you the value of the loss itself, so if you need it, it will require extra computations). I personally prefer `tfe.implicit_value_and_gradients()` when writing production code, and `tf.GradientTape` when experimenting in a Jupyter notebook.

**Edit**: In TF 2.0, it seems that only `tf.GradientTape` remains. Maybe the other functions will be added back, but I wouldn't count on it.

## Detailed example

Let's create a small function to highlight the differences:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tf.enable_eager_execution()

w1 = tfe.Variable(2.0)
w2 = tfe.Variable(3.0)
​
def weighted_sum(x1, x2):
    return w1 * x1 + w2 * x2

s = weighted_sum(5., 7.)
print(s.numpy()) # 31
```

## Using `tf.GradientTape`

Within a `GradientTape` context, all operations are recorded, then you can compute the gradients of any tensor computed within the context, with regards to any trainable variable. For example, this code computes `s` within the `GradientTape` context, and then computes the gradient of `s` with regards to `w1`. Since `s = w1 * x1 + w2 * x2`, the gradient of `s` with regards to `w1` is `x1`:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    s = weighted_sum(5., 7.)
​
[w1_grad] = tape.gradient(s, [w1])
print(w1_grad.numpy()) # 5.0 = gradient of s with regards to w1 = x1
```

## Using `tfe.gradients_function()`

This function returns another function that can compute the gradients of a function's returned value with regards to its parameters. For example, we can use it to define a function that will compute the gradients of `s` with regards to `x1` and `x2`:

```
grad_fn = tfe.gradients_function(weighted_sum)
x1_grad, x2_grad = grad_fn(5., 7.)
print(x1_grad.numpy()) # 2.0 = gradient of s with regards to x1 = w1
```

In the context of optimization, it would make more sense compute gradients with regards to variables that we can tweak. For this, we can change the `weighted_sum()` function to take `w1` and `w2` as parameters as well, and tell `tfe.gradients_function()` to only consider the parameters named `"w1"` and `"w2"`:

```
def weighted_sum_with_weights(w1, x1, w2, x2):
    return w1 * x1 + w2 * x2

grad_fn = tfe.gradients_function(weighted_sum_with_weights, params=["w1", "w2"])
[w1_grad, w2_grad] = grad_fn(w1, 5., w2, 7.)
print(w2_grad.numpy()) # 7.0 = gradient of s with regards to w2 = x2
```

## Using `tfe.implicit_gradients()`

This function returns another function that can compute the gradients of a function's returned value with regards to all trainable variables it depends on. Going back to the first version of `weighted_sum()`, we can use it to compute the gradients of `s` with regards to `w1` and `w2` without having to explicitly pass these variables. Note that the gradient function returns a list of gradient/variable pairs:

```
grad_fn = tfe.implicit_gradients(weighted_sum)
[(w1_grad, w1_var), (w2_grad, w2_var)] = grad_fn(5., 7.)
print(w1_grad.numpy()) # 5.0 = gradient of s with regards to w1 = x1

assert w1_var is w1
assert w2_var is w2
```

This function does seem like the simplest and most useful option, since generally we are interested in computing the gradients of the loss with regards to the model parameters (ie. variables).
Note: try making `w1` untrainable (`w1 = tfe.Variable(2., trainable=False)`) and redefine `weighted_sum()`, and you will see that `grad_fn` only returns the gradient of `s` with regards to `w2`.

## Using `tfe.implicit_value_and_gradients()`

This function is almost identical to `implicit_gradients()` except the function it creates also returns the result of the function being differentiated (in this case `weighted_sum()`):

```
grad_fn = tfe.implicit_value_and_gradients(weighted_sum)
s, [(w1_grad, w1_var), (w2_grad, w2_var)] = grad_fn(5., 7.)
print(s.numpy()) # 31.0 = s = w1 * x1 + w2 * x2
```

When you need both the output of a function and its gradients, this function can give you a nice performance boost, since you get the output of the function for free when computing the gradients using autodiff.